# How to get data form database without reloading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, css

I want to make a faq panel when user ask any question it show on the top of division without reloading the page for that i think i have to make a connection with database after every few second. Now the question is that how to make connection without reloading the page and how to show new question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), which allows you to retrieve data from the server with JavaScript, which you can then use to manipulate the DOM. The basis of Ajax is the `XMLHttpRequest` object, which allows you to retrieve data completely behind-the-scenes in JavaScript. Note that Ajax is limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but for what you're describing, that's fine — you'll be loading data from the same origin.
2. Frames (e.g., `iframe` elements), which you can load content into by setting their `src` property.

Of the two, Ajax is much more flexible.

References / further reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Applications APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#auto-toc-6)
- [XMLHttpRequest object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

---

Side note: Although obviously you can use `XMLHttpRequest` and the DOM methods directly, note that there are cross-browser differences (and outright bugs), which can be smoothed over for you by a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They also provide a lot of useful utility functionality, allowing you to focus on the actual problem you're trying to solve rather than the details of the plumbing.

For example, here's how you would send an Ajax request to a server using jQuery and have an element on the page updated with the HTML fragment the server sends back:

```
$("#target").load("get_the_data.php", {article: x});
```

That says: Request an HTML fragment from `get_the_data.php` sending it the parameter `article` with the value from the `x` variable, and put that HTML fragment inside the element that has the HTML `id` "target". That would be a good 10 lines of code if you didn't use a library. Now, that's not a lot, but repeat that over and over (and in the process deal with an IE bug around looking up elements by their `id`), and you see how it can add up.

I do recommend you read the references above so you know how the libraries are doing what they're doing (it's not magic), but there's no reason not to leverage the hard work people have done to make this stuff easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is AJAX. It is a way of contacting the server with only partial page refresh. I don't know how it works with php as i use asp.net but here is [a link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

It's Ajax turn. What you need is a technology called AJAX. You can find something usable in jQuery library that provides different methods to work with Ajax more easily.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You will create a relation with your server-side programming language and your database through a client-side scripting language (Javascript in this case).
This is an example of these realations:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into push/publish/subscription technologies. Few that i know are [pubnum](http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/php-push-api)  and [commet](http://cometd.org/)